# Custom Long Operation Success message

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm trying to show a custom success message instead of basic 'The operation has completed.' Does anybody know how to implement it for some specific long operation? (e.g. Only for voiding Reconciliation statement)[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicaly, one can throw `PXOperationCompletedException` from inside of the long operation to complete it with a custom message.
Here is an example

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, () =>
        {
            throw new PXOperationCompletedException("test");
        });
```

[image]